# Type of data, like ? is type of but in java

Tags: java, types

I'm trying to verify my `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` has worked they do print out the changed data.
It'd be nice if there were a `isTypeOf` style test to prove String has became an integer.
Is there anything similar in java?

Comment: im not guessing. thats why i want to ensure its worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use a Float.parseFloat(String) and catch a NumberFormatException like this:

```
public boolean isAnInt(String number)
{
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(number);
    } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean isFloat(String number)
{
    try {
        Float.parseFloat(number);
    } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I think there are better ways but I don't remmeber right now.

Answer (score 1):

parseInt and parseFloat will throw a NumberFormatException if something went wrong.